# TypeScript AMD with RequireJS does not build properly in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, requirejs, resharper, typescript1.8

Using Resharper and TypeScript(v 1.8.30) in VS 2015. the TypeScript files are compiled fine with RequireJS on saving, but not through the project build.

```
//b.ts file
export function createB() {
    return { };
}
```

Through compile on save, it looks fine:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    function createB() {
        return {};
    }
    exports.createB = createB;
});
//# sourceMappingURL=b.js.map
```

Compile through the project build, seem to not working with RequireJS as it is not wrapped with the define()

```
"use strict";
function createB() {
    return {};
}
exports.createB = createB;
//# sourceMappingURL=b.js.map
```

Not sure why it behaves differently?

Settings in the TextEditor:[image]

Settings in project properties:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by adding the tyscript configuration file tsconfig.json to the root of the script folder and added `"module": "amd"`.

Here is the tsconfig file that I have used to resolve the issue:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "amd"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just solved the problem, the issue was that I used command "tsc --init" to create the tsconfig.json file for the project, and the visual studio detects this file and disables the project properties from editing for TypeScriptBuild. I removed this file so that I can config the VS build, but the build didn't build the JS files properly for RequireJS. I found out it is related to this setting in the MSBuild properties `<TypeScriptJSXEmit>-1</TypeScriptJSXEmit>`, changed it to be `<TypeScriptJSXEmit>None</TypeScriptJSXEmit>` and it works. Thanks